# read files from different directories and split file name to create variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read data from a nested Directory into R for Analysis. I have tried

```
list.files(pattern = "*.mass", recursive =T) # .mass is the file Extension I´m interested in.
```

which creates a list of all files

```
> head(list.files(pattern = "*.mass", recursive = T))
[1] "No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/1/Test1_out.mass" "No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/2/Test1_out.mass"
[3] "No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/4/Test1_out.mass" "No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/5/Test1_out.mass"
[5] "No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/6/Test1_out.mass" "No_Vegetation/Rain17_60/No_MT/1/Test1_out.mass"
> tail(list.files(pattern = "*.mass", recursive = T))
[1] "vegetation/Rain20_45/No_MT/6/Test1_out.mass" "vegetation/Rain20_60/No_MT/1/Test1_out.mass"
[3] "vegetation/Rain20_60/No_MT/2/Test1_out.mass" "vegetation/Rain20_60/No_MT/4/Test1_out.mass"
[5] "vegetation/Rain20_60/No_MT/5/Test1_out.mass" "vegetation/Rain20_60/No_MT/6/Test1_out.mass"
```

Then I try reading the files using

```
dt <- list.files(pattern = "*.mass", recursive = T) %>% map_df(~fread(.))
str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  39814 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ time_[s]           : num  0 64.7 125.5 186.2 247.1 ...
 $ dt_[s]             : num  60 5.18 4.47 2.92 2.48 ...
 $ massDomain_[m3]    : num  0 6.18 11.78 17.34 22.88 ...
 $ massBound_[m3]     : num  0 -0.00923 -0.01781 -0.01316 -0.0127 ...
 $ massSource_[m3]    : num  0 0.496 0.428 0.28 0.238 ...
 $ massError_[-]      : num  0.00 1.72e-13 1.44e-15 1.76e-14 -1.11e-14 ...
 $ BoundaryFlow_[m3/s]: num  0 -0.00178 -0.00398 -0.0045 -0.00511 ...
 $ RainRate_[mm/hr]   : num  0 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 ...
 $ accumRain_[m3]     : num  0 7.22 13.99 20.77 27.56 ...
 $ inf_[m3/s]         : num  0 0.0158 0.0158 0.0158 0.0158 ...
 $ accumInf_[m3]      : num  0 1.02 1.98 2.94 3.9 ...
 $ perc_[m3/s]        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ bc1_[m3/s]         : num  0 0 -0.000257 -0.003607 -0.004206 ...
 $ bc1Acum_[m3]       : num  0 -0.0166 -0.2356 -0.4913 -0.7855 ..
```

and it combines all the files into one data.frame or data.table, without differentiating the files.

What I would like to do is to to create new string variables from the file names and add to the data.

for example, I would like to create variables like this:

```
veg <- c("vegetation", "No_Vegetation")
Rain <- c("Rain17_45", "Rain17", "Rain20_45", "Rain20_60")
Roughness <- c("MT", "No_MT")
Geom <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
```

the new variables are veg, Rain, Geom and Rougness, while the Vector entries are the data data that should span the entire dt. therefore, I want that for each new variable, the corect string should be assigned, depending on whether or not it finds the string in the file Name.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the `.f`part of `map_df` to add the filename as a column. Then `tstrsplit` could be invoked to make the new columns and add them in e.g below

```
list.files(pattern = "*.mass", recursive = T) %>% 
  map_df(., .f = function(x){
    dt <- fread(x)
    dt$file <- x
    dt
  })

tstrsplit("No_Vegetation/Rain17_45/No_MT/1/Test1_out.mass",
          "/")[1:4]
```

Comment: I have manipulated it to work for me. Thanks alot. after Splitting the file names, I subsetted them into different variables and then used `mutate()` to add them to the data. I just inspected and it´s exactly what I wanted to have at the end.